# Laravel 5 routes are not working

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I'm migrating from Laravel 4 to Laravel 5.

Only following is working:

```
Route::get('/some-url', function(){
    echo "Some text";
});
```

Following is not working:

```
Route::get('/get-customer-info', 'CustomerController@info');
```

I created the controller in: **app\Http\Controllers\CustomerController.php**

So, whenever I redirect to a controller, it always set **object not found**
Here is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
   function __construct()
   {
       View::share('root', URL::to('/'));
   }

   public function info()
   {
       echo "ok";
   }
}
```

I moved **index.php** file to the root.
Here is the **index.php** file on the

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: throw a `composer dump-autoload` command using your command prompt, in project root directory. hope it helps.

Comment: what is the full object not found error message?